# SQL server insert encoding

Tags: sql, encoding, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012 Management studio,
running the following command insert the data but modify/convert the "," to another char who look like a comma but is not (char code 8128):

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] VALUES(3,'City','Qu,bec')
```

I tried the Prefix N but it didnt worked:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[MyTable] VALUES(3,'City',N'Qu,bec')
```

However, if i use the "Edit" mode of Management studio, the good value is inserted.

The data type of the column is nvarchar(100)

I think it has something to do about Encoding but I cant find how to fix it. In my C# project, I use LinqToSql to extract the data and I end with the bad char (char code 8128) if the data was inserted with the command instead of the "Edit" mode.

I would appreciate a fix and a short explanation. Thx

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't worked"? Did you get an error? Or incorrect characters in the data? I copied your code and it inserted without any noticeable problems.

Comment: No error, just the same result with the wrong char

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert these values from code, then you would use the `N` prefix, and use the actual unicode character like so:

```
create table mytable (id int, type varchar(16), name nvarchar(64))
insert into mytable values (3,'City',N'Québec')

select * from mytable
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/JUBZS75211

returns:

```
+----+------+--------+
| id | type |  name  |
+----+------+--------+
|  3 | City | Québec |
+----+------+--------+
```